# Unity WebGL performance issues on Retina (MacBook)

Tags: performance, unity-game-engine, resolution, retina-display, unity-webgl

I developed a WebGL Unity 3D app with a 3d character that can navigate in the environment (mouse navigation and WASD) and interact with some objects.
On windows it is all great  and the FPS is 45-60 and the resolution is 1920 * 1xxx.
On Macs the performance drops to 13-17 because of Retina and the resolution is 3300 * 2100 (double the laptop's resolution).
How can I handle this ?
Any help would be appreciated.Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is the issue specific to a browser (firefox, safari, chrome, etc)? how is the performance in a standalone macOS build?

Comment: No, it's on all browsers.

Comment: I didn't try the standalone because I need it in WebGL.

Comment: If you try it, you would know, if it’s general issue or WebGL specific.

Comment: Ok I'll try..Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to add a JavaScript code to the html file to set the DPI to 1

Answer (score 1):

Thank you Siba for your hint. Though I had to search a bit how to actually do it for 2019.4.
Just in case anyone stumbles upon this, I did this in JavaScript, right before UnityLoader.instantiate:
`window.devicePixelRatio = 1;`

If you're using newer Unity versions, this thread might also help:
https://forum.unity.com/threads/webgl-retina-scaling.853144/

Answer (score 0):

In Unity if you go to *Edit menu > Project settings > Player | Resolution and  Presentation : Display Resolution Dialog*. You can change the default settings for your program.

[Here you can see the default ratio's your screen will be displayed in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l7pm1.png)

[This](https://learn.unity.com/course/performance-and-optimisation) is a course on unity's performance optimization

For more information go to [link](http://www.aclockworkberry.com/managing-screen-resolution-and-aspect-ratio-in-unity-3d/#:%7E:text=Shipping%20your%20game%20with%20the,fullscreen%20resolution%20for%20the%20game.)

Or the Unity [Desrciption](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Screen.SetResolution.html) itself.

Comment: Thank you, but I  couldn't find these options on WebGL.

Comment: They are available on the standalone tab but not WebGL tab.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so if you go into webGL, in unity itself. so: *WebGL > WebGL Player Settings > Resolution and Presentation*.

you will find this [screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eKuo0.png).

**Setting   Function**

*Default Canvas Width*
Set the width of the WebGL canvas element.

*Default Canvas Height*
Set the height of the WebGL canvas element.

*Run In Background*
Enable this option to allow your content to continue to run when the canvas or the browser window loses focus.

Comment: i will do some research. give me a bit of time.

Comment: Ok.. Thank you  so much

Comment: have you tried building it with the new settings? also you need to make sure that the resolution is fixed and will not change.

Comment: Yeah.. no change

Comment: I did a research and I think I should edit the javascript code (The output of the build)... Any clue about this?

Comment: well that would make some sense but i do not have enough knowledge of JS to tell you what to do. sorry.

Comment: No problem.. Thanks a lot anyway